# .htaccess does not reflete the changes on files

Tags: .htaccess

I did a site and instead of appcache o other i choose to use .htaccess file. The problem is, when i change a file, the changes does not appear(and i believe that is due to .htaccess file)

This is my .htaccess file :

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset ETag
</IfModule>
 FileETag None
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest "access plus 0 seconds"
# Html
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 0 seconds"
# Data
ExpiresByType text/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/json "access plus 0 seconds"
# Feed
ExpiresByType application/rss+xml "access plus 1 hour"
ExpiresByType application/atom+xml "access plus 1 hour"
# Favicon
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 week"
# Media: images, video, audio
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/ogg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType audio/ogg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/webm "access plus 1 month"
# HTC files
ExpiresByType text/x-component "access plus 1 month"
# Webfonts
ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType font/opentype "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"
# CSS / JS
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
#Força o IE a sempre carregar utilizando a última versão disponível
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1"
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|gif|png|jpeg|pdf|xml|oga|ogg|m4a|ogv|mp4|m4v|webm|svg|svgz|eot|ttf|otf|woff|ico|webp|appcache|manifest|htc|crx|oex|xpi|safariextz|vcf)$" >
Header unset X-UA-Compatible
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: "the changes does not appear" - what do you mean? Which "file"? Is the page (or resources) _cached_? If you clear the cache do you see the changes?

Comment: My changes in my html that was cached does not reflect in browser @user82217
 I see the changes if i clear the cache, but i dont want to do that bacause a normal user wont do that

Comment: Does a normal user _need_ to see the change as soon as the page changes? Does the page change often?

Comment: @user82217 yes, change often and user need to see as soon as changes :/

Answer (score 2):

You set caches for a week, a month, a year... it does exactly what you would expect: the browser caches the old version of your file for the specified period.

As you could see from the logs, your browser doesn't even access the files. You can force a reload with Ctrl+F5 or shorten the cache period. Of course the changes in your expiration time will affect only after the first expiration or forced reload.

Comment: Is there a method that you think that is better than .htaccess?

Comment: You haven't specified what you are trying to achieve, else than your cache settings... that are working exactly as set.

Comment: I was trying to achieve that, when i change my index.html for example, i didn't have to clear the cache manually to view this changes on the browser, because normal user won't clear manually the cache because he/she wont know if there is a change or not to be fetched

Comment: I see... there are also lines with 0 seconds. How about your environment? Is the mod_expires enabled? Is .htaccess allowed? Check from browsers developer tools which headers are actually sent.

Comment: @CatarinaNogueira If you want long cache times, version your assets